# How to navigate from Child Component to Parent in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have multiple Navigations nested together (Stacks and BottomTab) and i want to navigate from the child of a navigator to the top; consider the following example:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

function AuthNav() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Signup"
          component={Signup}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
} 

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Auth"
          component={AuthNav}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Say i want to move from my Signup screen back up to the App, and then navigate into the Home component, how would i go about doing that, also an explanation as to how the {independent: true} option works will be appreciated as well

Comment: you cannot use NavigationContainer twice on your project

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in previous answer and comment, you're using `NavigationContainer` twice. You cannot do that. If you want to navigate back to parent screen, you can use `navigation.goBack()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so basically the only time i can use NavigationContainer is on the root of the application?

Comment: Yes. Please give an upvote or mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: unfortunately not, i wasnt able to navigate to the Home component still, maybe i will make another post about the issue in more detail but thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong formatting for coding

use this,

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

function AuthNav() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Signup"
          component={Signup}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    
  );
} 

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Auth"
          component={AuthNav}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I hope it resolves your issue.